# How to hide a label of a dropdown with hide() function

Tags: html, ajax, laravel

I have 2 dropdowns (EmployeeType, Type) and a textbox (Rate) and I just want to hide "Type" and "Rate" according to the selected value of "EmployeeType". I've done it with no issues to the "Rate", but for the "Type" only the dropdown hides not the label. Can anyone help me to hide the label of the dropdown as well?

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="Designation">Employee Type</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="Designation" onchange="ajaxRate(this)" id="Designation">
            <option value="">--Select Employee Type--</option>
            <option value="Center">Center</option>
            <option value="Visiting">Visiting</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <span id="ajax_img3"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- designation-->
    <br/>

    <!-- 2019-03-18 Visiting Type -->
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="Type">Type</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="Type" id="TypeValue">
                <option value="">--Select Type--</option>
                <option value="Yes">Regular</option>
                <option value="No">Visiting</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" id='rate'>
        <label class="control-label" for="Rate">Hourly Rate</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="number" name="Rate" id='rateValue'/>
        </div>
    </div>

@include('includes.footer')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#rate").hide();
        // $("#Type").hide();
    });

    function ajaxRate(x) {
        if (x.value == 'Center') {
            $("#rate").hide();
            $("#rateValue").val('0');
            $("#TypeValue").show();
        } else {
            $("#rate").show();
            $("#rateValue").val('0');
            $("#TypeValue").hide();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function()
    {
        $("#rate").hide();
        // $("#Type").hide();
    });
    function ajaxRate(x)
    {
        if(x.value=='Center')
        {
            $("#rate").hide();
            $("#rateValue").val('0');
            $("#TypeValue").show();
    $("#TypeValue").parents(".control-group").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#rate").show();
            $("#rateValue").val('0');
            $("#TypeValue").hide();
$("#TypeValue").parents(".control-group").hide();
        }
```

}

You have to hide full div using parents or you have to add any id to main div to hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ajaxRate(x) {

            if(x.value=='Center')
            {
                $("#rate").hide();
                $("#rateValue").val('0');
                $("#TypeValue").closest('div.control-group').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#rate").show();
                $("#rateValue").val('0');
                $("#TypeValue").closest('div.control-group').hide();
            }
}
```